# Why does Apple use a special COREDATA_EXTERN qualifier instead of just extern?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

Sometimes I like to browse Apple source code to see how the pros do it, and sometimes learn a thing or two. I'm looking now at the header file for `NSManagedObjectContext.h`, and for their global variables, for say `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, they declare it like so:

```
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification;
```

whereas typically it would just be:

```
extern NSString * const NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
```

Cmd+clicking on COREDATA_EXTERN takes me to its definition:

```
#define COREDATA_EXTERN     extern
```

So `COREDATA_EXTERN` is just equal to `extern`, so my question is, why do they not just use `extern`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the CoreDataDefines.h file, you'll see a few different definitions for COREDATA_EXTERN, such as:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define COREDATA_EXTERN     extern "C"
```

or:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define COREDATA_EXTERN     extern "C" _NSWINDOWS_DLL_GOOP
```

This allows for some platform specific definitions, all contained under a single definition.

Windows goop, that's funny. What I'd like to know is when you would be compiling core data on a Windows platform....

Comment: Core Data has its roots in the [Enterprise Objects Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Objects_Framework), which was available on multiple platforms and architectures.

Comment: A more recent link will point you to the Yellow-Box DBM system, which pissed a lot of Windows developers off when it was discontinued.